# Drupal. Сильно разрастается таблица locales_source

Tags: drupal, перевод

Достался сайт, на котором сильно разрастается таблица `locales_source`. Нашел, что может быть из-за использования `t()` с динамическим содержанием, но посмотрев все кастомные модули и темы, ни чего не нашел подобного. Может кто-то сталкивался с этой проблемой? В чем еще может быть причина? Причем, в таблице содержаться как строки, так и цифры, что на мой взгляд, очень странно.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Может быть включен перевод нод? Какой нибудь i18n установлен?

Типа такого: https://www.drupal.org/node/987942, https://www.drupal.org/node/1841750

А если попробовать очистить таблицу?

Comment: i18n установлен. После очистки снова ростет.

Comment: Перевод нод включен?

Comment: а не подскажите, где это посмотреть?

Comment: В настройках типа материала, как-то так: /admin/structure/types/manage/news и там во вкладках искать.

Comment: Выбрали ответ лучшим… А что помогло-то опишите, пожалуйста?